# gitHooks not working in nested package.json

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, githooks, vue-cli-3

My git hooks does't get triggered. I pretty sure the reason is, because my `package.json` file isn't on the same level as my `.git`. So my `.git` dir structure looks something like this:

```
.git/...
.vscode/...
auth/...
core/...
www/package.json
www/scripts/verify-commit-msg.js
www/src/...
```

As you can see my package.json is nested inside my `www/` folder.

Within my `package.json, my gitHooks looks as follow.

```
"gitHooks": {
    "commit-msg": "node scripts/verify-commit-msg.js"
  }
```

Additional Note: It works fine if my `package.json` is on the same level as my `.git`

I know 1 solution is to put my `www` in its own git repo. For now I don't want to do that.

**I am using vue cli 3**, and I know they are using [yorky](https://github.com/Akryum/yorkie) for the githooks tooling.